# Writing hours and minutes to a text file using datetime in python

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I am trying to write a time to my textfile.

I have a list of rows. The first column (row[0] has a datetime value of an hour and a minute e.g (12:30). I want to write 12:30 to the textfile, however I get default values as well as the correct data.

What I want to do is to input a new item into the textfile, and then order the rows by time. I read that this can be easily done by converting the time string as a datetime object. I have tried do that as seen below:

Entire process:

```
        isValid = True
        print("You have selected to add a item to the datasheet, please follow the instructions carefully.")
        #Ask User for inputs.
        timeEaten = input("Please enter the Time the item was consumed at(HH:MM): ")
        itemMType = input("Please enter the Meal Type: ")
        itemDesc = input("Please enter the Description of the item : ")
        itemServing = input("Please enter the Serving size (in grams): ")
        itemKCal = input("Please enter the amount of calories (in kCal): ")
        itemFat = input("Please enter the amount of saturated fat in the item (in grams): ")
        #Validation
        ...
        if isValid==True:
            newItem = [str(timeEaten)," "+str(itemMType)," "+str(itemDesc)," "+str(itemServing)," "+str(itemKCal)," "+str(itemFat)]
            rowsToWrite = []
            #Thsi will contain the rows with the datetime element
            rowsToSort = []
            rowsToWrite.append(newItem)
            with open("datasheet.txt") as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                for row in reader:
                    rowsToWrite.append(row)
            for row in rowsToWrite:
                tempList=[datetime.strptime((str(row[0]).strip()),'%H:%M'),row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]]
                rowsToSort.append(tempList)
            rowsToSort = sorted(rowsToSort)
            print(rowsToSort)
            with open("datasheet.txt", 'w') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                for row in rowsToSort:
                    row[0] = row[0][11:16]
                    row[5].strip()
                    writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            print("Item not valid, returning to menu")
```

Expected output:

```
08:11, Breakfast, Cereal, 200, 210, 1.6
08:20, Breakfast, Pancake, 38, 74, 1.4
08:20, Breakfast, Coffee, 200, 20, 0.4
10.30, Snack, Chocolate, 10, 56, 2.5
12:15, Lunch, Soup, 300, 170, 0.3
12:20, Lunch, Sandwich, 180, 365, 2.3
12:25, Lunch, Yogurt, 125, 65, 0.1
14:00, Snack, Apple, 100, 51, 0.1
17:30, Dinner, Fries, 70, 129, 0.6
17.30, Dinner, Chicken Breast, 155, 240, 3.5
17.30, Dinner, Broccoli, 85, 29, 0.1
18:00, Snack, Coffee, 200, 20, 0.4
20:00, Snack, Coffee, 200, 20, 0.4
20:00, Snack, Chocolate, 10, 56, 2.5
22:30, Snack, Cereal, 200, 210, 1.6
```

Actual current output:

```
1900-01-01 08:11:00, Breakfast, Cereal, 200, 210, 1.6
1900-01-01 08:20:00, Breakfast, Coffee, 200, 20, 0.4
1900-01-01 08:20:00, Breakfast, Pancake, 38, 74, 1.4
1900-01-01 10:30:00, Snack, Chocolate, 10, 56, 2.5
1900-01-01 12:15:00, Lunch, Soup, 300, 170, 0.3
1900-01-01 12:20:00, Lunch, Sandwich, 180, 365, 2.3
1900-01-01 12:25:00, Lunch, Yogurt, 125, 65, 0.1
1900-01-01 14:00:00, Snack, Apple, 100, 51, 0.1
1900-01-01 17:30:00, Dinner, Broccoli, 85, 29, 0.1
1900-01-01 17:30:00, Dinner, Chicken Breast, 155, 240, 3.5
1900-01-01 17:30:00, Dinner, Fries, 70, 129, 0.6
1900-01-01 18:00:00, Snack, Coffee, 200, 20, 0.4
1900-01-01 20:00:00, Snack, Chocolate, 10, 56, 2.5
1900-01-01 20:00:00, Snack, Coffee, 200, 20, 0.4
1900-01-01 22:30:00, Snack, Cereal, 200, 210, 1.6
```

Comment: `writer.writerow(tempList)` ... you need to write the row you modified not the original unmodified entry

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks, but I still get an error , ValueError: time data '1900-01-01 08:11:00' does not match format '%H:%M'

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here; strftime() only makes sense when used on a datetime *object*, not on a string (which row[0] appears to be).  Can you provide and example of a few lines of the input file?

Comment: @CodeRedacted I have added more detail to the question

Comment: @stovfl sorry that produces the error: TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @LyraOrwell  ***`TypeError: 'datetime.datetime'`***: So `row[0]` is of type `datetime` then your first used `.strftime(..)` should work?

Comment: @stovfl i need to convert the datetime object back into a string. The only reason it becomes a datetime object is to carry out the sort.

Comment: @LyraOrwell ***"back into a string."***: `.strftime(...` will just do this.

Comment: @LyraOrwell Doublecheck the `ValueError: time data...` it probably comes from this line: `tempList=[datetime ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202949/discussion-between-stovfl-and-lyra-orwell).